# How create a new launcher with bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want create a new launcher in the Application -> Game menu with bash shell.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu there's a script for panel manipulation
`/usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-panel-add --launcher=yourApp.desktop`
Example for yourApp.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Type=Application  
Exec=vim  
Terminal=true  
Name[en_GB]=Vim
```